# GA4 data showing different results for Users/Sessions than Big Query question

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to put together a report that shows the following, by medium and source:
Total Users
Engaged Sessions
Engagement Time

I've got the query to give me results, however when I import them into Looker, my results are vastly different, as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of data]
Is there a reason my GA4 data is so off from my query?
Here's my query for reference

```
WITH prep AS (
  SELECT
    traffic_source.medium,
    traffic_source.source,
    event_date,
    user_pseudo_id,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS ga_session_id,
    CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id')) AS session_id,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'session_engaged') AS engaged_sessions,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'engagement_time_msec') AS engagement_time_msec
  FROM `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*`
)
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS num_of_sessions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT 
    CASE
      WHEN engaged_sessions = '1' THEN CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST(ga_session_id AS STRING)) ELSE NULL
    END) AS num_of_engaged_sessions,
  AVG(engagement_time_msec) AS engagement_time_msec,
  event_date,
  medium,
  source
FROM prep
GROUP BY
  event_date,
  medium,
  source;
```